# Constant BSODs from boot drive corruptions [Windows 10]

Tags: ssd, windows-10, bsod

**Prelude:**

I have ran memtest86 twice, Windows Memory Diagnostic and Intel Extreme Tuning Utility tests once with no faults or errors found.

All commands in Command Prompt were ran using Admin Privileges.

Hardware: http://pastebin.com/Kr09ZMVQ

---

**Problem:**

I have been using Windows 10 Pro. 64-bit (upgraded from Windows 7 Pro. 64-bit) for the past month and I have had endless amounts of blue screens. After investigating, I have narrowed the issue to the boot SSD, but I haven't been able to actually fix it.

I downloaded the associated software for my SSD, [Samsung Magician](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/downloads/software/Samsung_Magician_46_Installation_Guide.pdf), which allowed to enable something called "[Over Provisioning](http://www.edn.com/design/systems-design/4404566/Understanding-SSD-over-provisioning)," which delayed the blue screens for about six or seven hours.

It also comes with a S.M.A.R.T. analyzing tool, the results of which can be seen here: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H40LX.png), as you can see, it's all good.

Except every, single, time I run `sfc /scannow`, [it always tells me that I have corrupt files and was unable to fix them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9tO2.png).

In the image, it tells me that it gave me a log showing me all the files it couldn't fix, which you can see a partial of [here](http://pastebin.com/VhAtaCQB), and a [full one here](https://mega.nz/#!rltSXZxL!IeUVWLax4p7E0ijKP4eDxT2C0CLDNwA_W18FIUKh-5o). A quick glance shows that there's *a lot* of wrongful and double ownership errors.

I tried another solution, which was running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, but that only gave me this: `Error: 1726 \ The remote procedure call failed`, and [this log](https://mega.nz/#!u8VVBJhK!Xma8tvAH9C9RJgbT07ZsXyQflWEhnkFrbHwvHkQB8oU). Apparently [people have been solving this problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/recieving-error-1726-dismexe-while-was-trying-to/f6dab7bd-bf1f-492e-a39c-1e9532b8f164)  by closing whatever application('s) is running "dxgi.dll" and figuring that out by running [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), and it tells me that one of programs running "dxgi.dll" is [Windows File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0pvg.png).

Update: Closing every application running "dxgi.dll" and rerunning the `Dism` string above didn't solve anything, it result with the same 1726 error.

Someone please help me, I've had these incredibly arcane problems annoy the bejesus out of me for quite some time, and I have no idea where to go from here :/

---

**Downloads:**

- [BSOD Minidump files](https://mega.nz/#!ug9QSQKK!j3PXpSYQx2v8Ixk-uDrReOQsOKoIFBLioXyyiC1sW68) - [BSOD viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html#DownloadLinks) - [Screenshot of Blue Screen's w/ a lot of info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqent.png)
- [CrystalDiskInfo, request by DrZoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A06nP.png)

Comment: After looking at some of your dump files, I saw the 3b blue screen was semi common. I had a problem with that a while ago. Memtest86 only once showed one error. I then ran Memtest several times again and nothing happened. I reseated the RAM and it stopped the BSOD. It was weird because the RAM was installed for several months before it started to happen. As far as the SSD, have you used something like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) to check the health of the disk? It could be possible that it has gone bad. Let us know what CrystalDisk says.

Comment: I thought of another thing. If you let the computer idle, will it BSOD too, or does it only do this when you are doing something?

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you for the reponse! I tried reseating the RAM awhile to the alternate channel, but the computer would go through many restarts and would usually stop at CPU initialization before restarting again (motherboard has a mini-basic LED display). I will run CrystalDiskInfo and return the results.

Comment: @DrZoo It's pretty rare for it to BSOD when idle, most times it happens is at startup consecutively about 2-3 times before remaining stable for awhile. Sometimes when I exit an application, it BSODs, and others are during gameplay.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but it could be a faulty PSU that is causing some of this. If it's not producing enough power for some reason it could very likely be a culprit of your troubles. After all, you do have a lengthy dump collection.

Comment: @DrZoo I added the [CrystalDiskInfo](http://i.imgur.com/MldmAIT.png), which reports that it's fine, I guess you could be right on the PSU, awhile ago I added a hard drive that I removed from an old Xbox 360. I'll try that and come back here.

Comment: @DrZoo Alright, I disconnected the extra hard drive, but that still led to a Blue Screen. I checked Device Manager and was able to install a [chipset driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20775) for "SM Bus," so everything's fine there, now. After looking through the [DISM repair logs](http://pastebin.com/J8ZcqDpK), it "failed [on] finalizing changes," it then points to the CBS log which basically said that it "failed on regenerating file...'SHCore.dll.'" Any ideas on that? Microsoft recommends [here](https://goo.gl/pSHxBo) to get good files from someone else.

Comment: So you're saying you just need to try and replace that dll with a known good one?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFgjF8HEbPdUDBybXpYSmhYOFU/view?usp=sharing) to my `SHCore.dll`

Comment: @DrZoo Sorry for not responding, everytime I try to, my PC bluescreens, I'd love to take a screenshot of the bluescreens, but Snipping Tool jus crashes. Thanks for the download, but it doesn't appear to be the correct one, according to the error log, it references:  SHCore.dll(.mui?) in `WinSxS\x86_microsoft...` as broken, and IMJPAPI.dll in `System32\IME\IMEJP\,` as shown **[here](http://imgur.com/a/IVuRq)**. Sorry for not being specific, I should've realized that there are more, thanks for all the help. Just for kicks, I checked the one you sent me **[here](http://i.imgur.com/Aboedco.png)**.

Answer (score 0):

I just had almost an identical problem on my samsung 840 pro 512gb ssd. What I did to fix it was did a fresh install of windows 10. But even after that I were still getting random bluescreens multiple times daily and it is extremely FRUSTRATING!!! So in a last ditch effort I OVERCLOCKED my cpu and I havent had a hiccup since. I didnt mess with any voltages or anything (yet) all i did was increase the multiplier and am sitting at a stable 4.3ghz and the OS is more responsive as well. It has been 4 days and I havent had a single bluescreen or hiccup.

Comment: i also want to add that the bluescreens i were getting were because of random dll's. sfc /scannow always returned fine. But if you have upgraded to windows 10, you can now reinstall fresh from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

i think i solved the situation guys.
first disable superfetch and prefetch.
also disable indexing . u can search online on how to do that.

what happens is the there is memory bug somehow and the prefetch and superfetch is eating ram and cpu cycles more and more until it overflows giving you the blue screen of death...
if you have ssd you dont need indexing prefetch and superfetch .

Comment: I promise you there isn't a memory leak superfetch and prefetch....

Comment: @Ramhound **I actually finally figured out the problem.** So I pulled out both my RAM sticks and found that the contacts on one of them was covered in some black soot-thing? Whatever it was, it damaged the contacts, so I got new sticks of RAM and it works fine now. The RAM contacts in the motherboard may require cleaning later, but alright for now.

I still don't understand how Memtest86 didn't pickup on that though. Also thanks you guys for still trying to fix this.